# I am trying to scrape prices off of Amazon with python, but i get an AttributeError

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am trying to scrape info off of Amazon, but i get an AttributeError. Here is the code:

```
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: Which line failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the find function incorrectly. It should look something like this:

```
title = soup.find("div", class_="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find("div", class_="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
```

`div` might need to be replaced with `span` or `p` depending on what you are looking for.

Also, it is possible that it still returns None and if that is the case, I would double-check that what you are looking for exists.